# Is there a "do this at most X times" syntax in PHP which I'm unaware of?

Tags: php

I often need to have a loop that in theory could go on forever, but which should stop after X tries in order to avoid eternal loops. I currently have to do:

```
$counter = 0;

while (1)
{
    if ($counter > 500)
        break;

    if (condition_has_been_met)
        break;

    // actual logic

    $counter++;
}
```

I guess I could simplify my own code with:

```
$counter = 0;

while ($counter < 500)
{
    if (condition_has_been_met)
        break;

    // actual logic

    $counter++;
}
```

... but it's still ugly IMO. And I can't think of way I'd "functionalize" this on my own.

Is there some nice unknown (to me) syntax to instead do this?

```
do at most (50)
{
    if (condition_has_been_met)
        break;

    // actual logic
}
```

It seems common enough to warrant such a special syntax, and since I keep discovering features in PHP after decades of using it, I might as well ask.

Comment: Um... what's wrong with just using a `for` loop?

Comment: I used to use them for everything, but they are not pretty. But maybe it makes sense after all... Hmm.

Comment: They're a lot prettier than using `while` loops with a `$counter` variable that is scoped outside the `while` loop.

Comment: If you put the $counter = 0; inside the loop, it will just keep getting reset...

Comment: You can use a do...while loop with the a condition `$counter <= 50` or you can use a simple while loop with two condition inside it like: `if (condition_has_been_met || $counter > 50)  break;`.

Comment: @user11555230 Obviously. That's why you should use a `for` loop.